# Where to put the comma on the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

Where do I put the comma in:

> It would be pretty implausible to make a claim of your distributed patch
>   that while directly intended to modify GPL source it wouldn't itself
>   be GPL when that's precisely the requirement.

In there?:

> It would be pretty implausible to make a claim of your distributed patch
>   that while directly intended to modify GPL source it wouldn't itself
>   be **GPL,** when that's precisely the requirement.

Or nowhere?

I require assistance.

Comment: Commas will not help your here. Rewrite it using separate sentences.

Comment: @michael.hor257k no.

Comment: [shrug] See if I care.

Comment: @michael.hor257k same to you, good sir. :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without commas, your sentence is difficult to follow. If you use commas to mark out the adverbial clauses, you'd make it much easier for the reader to follow your meaning. Like this:

> It would be pretty implausible to claim that your distributed patch, while directly intended to modify GPL source, would not itself be GPL, when that's precisely the requirement.